# JSON Parsing in Xcode returning error

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to parse the following JSON information that comes out of my PHP file:

```
{
"netSales":0,
"voidSales":0,
"discountSales":0,
"guestCount":null,
"servedCount":null,
"loggedIn":9
}
```

My string is set something like this:

```
       NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:salesStr];
            NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];



            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


            NSLog(@"response type is %@",[json class]);

            //Set up our cities array



            arrayOfStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)



            {


                NSString * netSales = json[i][@"netSales"];
                NSString * voids = json[i][@"voidSales"];
                NSString * discounts = json[i][@"discountSales"];
                NSString * guestCount = json[i][@"guestCount"];
                NSString * peopleServed = json[i][@"servedCount"];
                NSString * employeesClock = json[i][@"loggedIn"];




                Store * myStore = [[Store alloc]initWithNetSales: (NSString *) netSales andVoids: (NSString *) voids andDiscounts: (NSString *) discounts andGuestCount: (NSString *) guestCount andPeopleServed: (NSString *) peopleServed andEmployeesClock: (NSString *) employeesClock];




                [arrayOfStore addObject:myStore];
```

But it's returning the error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ddb930'
```

What does this error mean?

EDIT: I extended my code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message, "[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent", is informing you that you attempted to call `objectAtIndex` (an array method) on an object that was really a dictionary.

Your code snippet appears to assume that the JSON is an array of dictionaries. But on the basis of what you've shared with us, it looks like a simple dictionary. That is consistent with the error message you received. You could remedy this by just calling `objectForKey`, and eliminate the call to `objectAtIndex`.

By the way, `netSales` appears to be a number, not a string, so use `NSNumber` rather than `NSString`.

So, putting those together, I think you'd want:

```
NSNumber *netSales = json[@"netSales"];  // or [json objectForKey:@"netSales"];
```

Comment: I edited the code in my above post. Does your answer still remain if my code looks like this?

Comment: Yes.  It looks like you're trying to iterate through an array, but there is no array.

Comment: json variable is of what type ??

Comment: @SquirrelInControl My answer is based upon the JSON you shared with us (which is a simple dictionary, not an array of dictionaries). If the sample JSON is representative, then this is the case. Look at the error, "[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent" ... that means that you tried to call `objectAtIndex` on an object that wasn't an array, but rather was a dictionary. This is also consistent with my diagnosis.